# JMS flow control

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jms, message-driven-bean, ejb-timer

I need to create a JMS consumer for which I can dinamically set the dequeue rate, something like N message per minute/second.

If I use the message-driven beans I can control the pool size, but I can't introduce a wait in a clean way, I can use sleep, but I don't know if it is a good idea.

Some AS admit a flow-control for JMS, but it's not JEE standard.
Maybe I could use timers service, but in this hypothesis I can't have an ejb pool, anyway not a pool controlled by the AS.

Comment: It may be helpful if you describe your problem in more detail. Someone may be able to come up with a better mechanism. Is JMS part of your solution or one of your requirements?

Comment: The JMS is a requirement.

Comment: I need to take charge of requests using a WS that write on a JMS queue. The process that dequeue from this JMS queue must have a throttling control

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use timer service for this purpose.

And you definitely can use timer service with stateless beans, which are pooled. You might need to check out more details here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

If you consider some parallel processing, or there are some other users of timer service on the same server - you have to provide timer service thread pool with sufficient number of threads.

Comment: I think that the timer is not pooled, I tried and every (for example) 10 seconds, it starts 1 timer

Comment: Not a timer, but timer thread pool and stateless bean pool. What do you mean by starting one timer?